# Why is $request->file('document') not being recognized? Always is null

Tags: laravel-5, file-upload, axios

For some reason, I cannot quite pin-point the reason for my application to fail to send a file with the request body.  I have tried all manners of configuring the request header, but to no avail.  I know it's not my end-point in Laravel because Postman works just fine with it.

Various header comibinations I have tried:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'multipart/form-data'

OR

'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'multipart/form-data'

OR

'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'multipart/form-data'
```

When ever I have my endpoint check to see if $request->file('document') is null, it always comes back true.

Here is my api code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $value = $request->file('document')->storeAs(
    $request->input('path'), $request->input('name')
  );

  return response()->json($value, 201);
}
```

Here is the last set of header's that was used and failed:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 164
Content-Transfer-Encoding: multipart/form-data
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d=eyJpdiI6IjhZMXRwM3BSYnlsMUdlUHQ1OEVzZkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibFJBV3AxaHU0T3BJY1M5UGRQZG5YdmhxTndWYXRRRHFsZlhEZ0tNa1NqWnlFZndwUGdkeGxFNzZXVW53OUxKMWJ0Q0s3VkFxZTM5T1dKUTdQVE5HbHVhcHBoS29rMllQb1wvbUhKeWFMcjdOOGU3elRYWWlyV3daY1duUUZCb1k1amE3aEVHWEN5SkJLZFVCNnNlRlJIa0hVT2FGb1poVjhCZzVOR21EMUttND0iLCJtYWMiOiI2YjFjYTA5MzcyYzcxMDk4OWFmNzJlNTMzMzQ0ODRkYTZmYzEzZDNjYmQ2YTdiNmZhZWFhODc2NWM0MWExMzZiIn0%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ikh4R1JhSXJ4M1IycmJTNmFsRjRic0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib0xpQzZqaHRRRFQ3V0RQU0lVT3VSdmU4RFwvS3MwSWpSeTdmOURVZE9kRlhPaTBFeWlBOHljQ1F4aGt0VEFIbWwiLCJtYWMiOiI3MjcyMGM5YzIwZjE5NTFkOTQyNjA3MDlmOTJjMjY0OTg2NGViZWY5NzYwZmJlNGEyYmM0MzFmNDYxMDRlN2U5In0%3D; conversion_session=eyJpdiI6InIwc2NRMzZhc1RZdWZtMDl0OFVMaHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNmY5MjJUYTNteW5zVG9MVmlmXC90a0FCaTlEY3VhS0w2UXYreUtmdG5yUE5IUnpWVE1qTWthemdnSzRKbmE5NWEiLCJtYWMiOiJjNDkzZTVlNzE0YjBhMDRiNDU3ZmQxMzNlZDkzMjQ1MWQ2YTcxMzYxODU0ZGMyYTFkOTZhYjA2ZmUwNDZhOGQ2In0%3D
Host: conversion:8000
Origin: http://conversion:8000
Referer: http://conversion:8000/accounts/1/projects/1?_token=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN: // Not pasted here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, that I was assigning my post data incorrectly for the files.  A tutorial had instructed my incorrectly and I found another one that showed me the correct way.